stm32f103re chip with sim7080g. Using FreeRTOS: cellular_interface
I’m a newbie to embedded, just starting out.
This time, I’m trying to make LTE connection using stm32f103re chip and SIM7080G.
Fortunately, I succeeded in basic setup through stm32cubemx and succeeded in GPIO control and UART control.
I even checked the LTE connection using AT commands.
However, I had problems sending long word commands, which made me realize the need for an RTOS. I saw that FreeRTOS can be set up on stm32cubemx, and I am trying to connect to the test server using FreeRTOS: coreHTTP, but I don’t know where to start.
If you don’t mind, is there an example that can be run directly on stm32cubemx with IAR? I was able to see some demos of FreeRTOS, but I still don’t know how to get started.
